# How to write code that implements Grey-edge color correction method?

Tags: python, image-processing

I need function in python that implements grey edge method for color correction. Function should get image that is type numpy and return corrected image.

I explored how grey-edge works ( https://www.researchgate.net/publication/49856707_Computational_Color_Constancy_Survey_and_Experiments , http://lear.inrialpes.fr/people/vandeweijer/papers/cr2542.pdf ) and I wrote a function using numpy. I was sure this was good logic but it seems like it isn't. I gave my everything to try to understand what should happen.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
def grey_edge(img: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    img = img.astype(np.float32)
    # Convert image to opponent color space
    O1 = img[..., 0] - 0.5 * img[..., 1] - 0.5 * img[..., 2]
    O2 = 0.5 * img[..., 0] - 0.5 * img[..., 1] + img[..., 2]
    O3 = 0.5 * img[..., 0] + img[..., 1] - 0.5 * img[..., 2]
    img_opponent = np.stack([O1, O2, O3], axis=-1)

    # Calculate color derivatives using OpenCV
    color_derivatives = np.zeros_like(img)
    for channel in range(3):
        color_derivatives[..., channel] = cv2.Sobel(img_opponent[..., channel], cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0)

    # Find average color derivative
    avg_derivative = color_derivatives.mean(axis=(0, 1))
    
    # Perform the skewing operation
    k = 1 / avg_derivative
    color_derivatives *= k

    # Transform the image back to the original color space
    img_corrected = np.zeros_like(img)
    img_corrected[..., 0] = O1 + k[0] * O3
    img_corrected[..., 1] = O2 + k[1] * O3
    img_corrected[..., 2] = O3 + k[2] * O3

    # Clipping the pixels value above 1 and below 0
    img_corrected = np.clip(img_corrected, 0, 1)
    return img_corrected


if __name__ == '__main__':
    image = io.imread("images/1.png") 
    plt.imshow(image)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.waitforbuttonpress()
    image = grey_edge(image)
    plt.imshow(image)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.waitforbuttonpress()
```

This is my code.
Output:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4A2r.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDRkf.png

It is clearly not working, but I don't know how to change in logic.

Comment: I'm guessing (I googled) that those names are taken directly from the secret papers (same authors, two papers). it's written weirdly.

Comment: the second paper seems to be a more fleshed out version of the first, so here's the second one: https://staff.science.uva.nl/th.gevers/pub/GeversTIP07.pdf

Comment: "I want to avoid conversion to numpy." Why? with `np.asarray()` you should have an array that references the data in the Torch object, it's essentially free to do this. Why are you making your life difficult trying to avoid it?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz this is the paper I used to learn about this: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/49856707_Computational_Color_Constancy_Survey_and_Experiments . Also this one: http://lear.inrialpes.fr/people/vandeweijer/papers/cr2542.pdf.

Comment: @Rotem this paper: lear.inrialpes.fr/people/vandeweijer/papers/cr2542.pdf is where  the O1, O2, O3 come from. Later today I will add imports and usage of function.

Comment: @CrisLuengo well I thought that tensors "work faster" then numpys.

Comment: the edit of your post contains a broken link... with ellipsis (`...`). please review how you copied that link.

Comment: @Rotem I edited code and I will focus on numpy not on torch

Comment: @Neytiri The subject of the question is interesting. My apologies, I am going to answer your question. I don't think I can post a good answer...